# UITapGestureRecognizer on UILabel is crashing in swift 3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Hi i want to add tap gesture on `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell` . here i have implemented the code like this.

```
override func awakeFromNib() 
  {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
     #selector(self.tapFunction))
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("tap working")
}
```

but it is giving me error like this

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this?

Comment: Because your #selector(self.tapFunction) is wrong where is sender argument ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya can you tell me what is the exact syntax

Comment: Try to `#selector(self.tapFunction(_:)))` instead of `#selector(self.tapFunction))`.

Comment: Check Sh_Khan's answer and @objc missing in your mehod

Comment: @asifsaifi Close your question as typo mistake

Answer (score 3):

This should be

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.tapFunction(_:)))
```

If you use Swift 4 add `@objc`

```
@objc func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  print("tap working")

}
```

Comment: No it is fine. I don't like to answer in 1 -2 line :D

Comment: No need to write an essay =D

Comment: Ya that's why we have comment section provided :XD

Comment: guyz i am  using swift 3  not swift 4.  so @objc will not work i guess.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Comment section is not for writing answers. It is for ask clarifications. So I think one line can answer the question, you can write it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

its working now with the same code . **Just i deleted the cell and created a new UITableviewCell. i guess it may be xcode bug**

```
    override func awakeFromNib() 
  {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
     #selector(self.tapFunction))
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("tap working")
}
```